# Subir una app nueva y firmar con el servicio Google Play App Signing

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

Quiero publicar una nueva app y por ello he activado lo de `Google Play App Signing` la poca información que corre y detalle de los pasos estoy que no paso del punto 1 [Firma tu nuevo APK con la clave de carga](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

En la sección Firma, se puede descargar la clave de carga que es un archivo `deployment_cert.der`

Pero que se tiene que hacer con ese archivo, donde lo configuro con Android studio?

Si subo el apk firmando mediante un `keystore` como hago normalmente pues me sale ese error:

> Error en la carga Subiste un APK que está firmado con una clave que
>   también se usa para firmar los APK que se envían a los usuarios. Como
>   estás inscrito en el programa de firma de apps, debes utilizar una
>   clave nueva antes de subir el archivo.

#### Pruebas

Normalmente uso uno para todas las apps, pero por lo visto he tenido que generar uno `keystore` nuevo:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias`

Me pregunta para asignar password, le inserto, todos los campos que pregunta también... se genera un `my-upload-key.jks` firmo el app des de android studio haciendo referencia al archivo alias: my-alias y su password, se genera el apk se sube perfectamente.

Ahora en el apartado `firmas` de googleplay console aparece para descargar `Subir certificado` que se puede descargar es un `upload_cert.der`

**Escenario 1 - perdida del keystore original**

Teniendo en cuenta que el servicio de `Google Play App Signing` es para que si el usuario pierde el keystore `my-upload-key.jks` se pueda restablecer sin problema.

Genero otro `my-upload-key.jks` usando otro password, firmo el apk y lo subo me salta el error (obviamente):

> Error en la carga Subiste un archivo APK que no está firmado con el
>   certificado de carga y deberías usar el mismo. El certificado de carga
>   tiene la huella digital [ SHA1: ... :89:45 ] y el certificado que
>   usaste para firmar el APK tiene la huella digital [ SHA1: ... :B6:F0 ]

Buscando por internet he encontrado como importar un certificado `der` pues inserto el `upload_cert.der` con un alias `my-alias2`

`keytool -importcert -file openssl_crt.der -keystore my-upload-key.jks -alias my-alias2 -keypass n1k2e3y4p5a6s7s`

paso: me pregunta si es un certificado seguro: si

Ahora mirando dentro del archivo del keystore aparece la firma correcta que se debe subir el apk.

En el cuadro de dialogo, pongo la clave del keystore, pulso desplegable para seleccionar `my-alias2`, el campo de clave del alias le pongo el establecido `n1k2e3y4p5a6s7s` y me salta error con:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key my-alias2 from store "my-upload-key.jks": trusted certificate entries are not password-protected

Por lo visto no el comando de importación la parte `-keypass ...` es como si no hiciera afecto, pero el proceso de firma en el cuadro de diálogo no me deja continuar si no meto alguna.

**Lo que me falta por probar**

Me falta probar de firmar el apk usando en modo comando, para ver si es posible sin usar clave en el alias del certificado de subida.

**¿Cómo se hace para firmar un apk en modo comando, bajo Windows?**

Comment: Me estoy mirando el video de presentación: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tdGAP927dk

Comment: puede ser de ayuda http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/Certificate-Format-keytool-Import-in-DER-and-PEM.html

Comment: Hola @Webserveis, encontraste la solución? Me encuentro con el mismo problema.